# Unity: How do I get the coordinates of the vertices of a blender mesh?

Tags: unity, blender, coordinates

I have gameobjects in my scene called icospheres that I have made in Blender, and I am trying to get the coordinates of their vertices. Below is an image of my scene; each triangle is a separate gameobject, blender mesh and is called an icosphere:

[image]

Here is the code I am using:

```
    var meshFilter = icosphere.GetComponent<MeshFilter>();
    var vertices = meshFilter.mesh.vertices;
    GameObject.Find("Fauna Manager").GetComponent<FaunaManager>().PlaceFauna(tree, vertices[0], icosphere);
    GameObject.Find("Fauna Manager").GetComponent<FaunaManager>().PlaceFauna(tree, vertices[1], icosphere);
    GameObject.Find("Fauna Manager").GetComponent<FaunaManager>().PlaceFauna(tree, vertices[2], icosphere);
```

The bottom 3 lines of code call a function that should in theory place another gameobject on top of the 3 coordinates that have been calculated above, however this does not happen. The tree-placing functions work completely and have been tested so the problem is definitely with the coordinates. I printed out the coordinates and the length of the array that holds them. The array is of length 3 as it should be however the coordinates are completely off. The trees have been placed a long way away from the icosphere which means the coordinates are clearly wrong. Where have I gone wrong?

```
example of coordinates: -0.1, 0.0, -0.1
centre of icosphere for reference: -0.7431812, 0.4044746, -4.932096
```

Above you can see that the coordinates are well off

Comment: Did you remember to take into account the position/scale/rotation of the mesh object?

Comment: @DMGregory no I didn’t, how can I edit my code to include this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you might not be transforming the vertices by the transformation of the object in the scene.

```
Vector3 worldPoint = icosphere.transform.TransformPoint(localPoint);
```

The vertices of a mesh are stored in object-local space. So you need to transform them through to world space if you want objects under a different parent to line up.

Alternatively, you can parent your trees to the mesh object and set their `localPosition` instead.

Comment: What is the variable localPoint in my case? Is it vertices? Because it doesn’t like the fact that one is Vector3 and the other is Vector3[]

Comment: Then index one point, not multiple points.

Comment: works perfectly, much appreciated